# How to make one object follow another

Tags: c++, object, tracking

I am making a game and I have my hero and enemy. Now I want enemy to follow hero when distance between them is 400 for example. 
How can I make it work.
Here is what I ve got so far, but it doe not work.
Objects::calcAngle(Objects* obj) - calculates angle between central points of 2 objects.

```
float Objects::calcAngle(Objects* obj){
    float dx = obj->X - this->X; 
    float dy = obj->Y - this->Y;
    float angle=atan(dy/dx)*180/PI;
    return angle;
}

void Enemy::Attack(mainCar* car){
    float angle=0;
    angle=this->calcAngle(car);
    if(this->Distance(car)<400){
        this->attack=true;
        this->heading=this->calcAngle(car)+90; 
        this->Vtri=abs(this->Vtri);
    } else if (this->Distance(car)>400) {
        this->attack=false;
    }
}
```

Vtri is speed of movement.
heading is direction  in degrees.

If you can give me a link to where it is described or just tell me here, it would be great. I have 2 days to submitt my project.

Comment: Still looking at your code, but I noticed you have under the if statement in the Attack function 'this->attack==true;' - it should probably be 'this->attack=true;'

Comment: Without understanding what the problem is, I can't really say much more. So like Mr. Lister said, how does it not work?

Comment: this->attack=true; just indicates that enemy attacks now(yeah, there should be one "=" sign). The problem is that I want the enemy head to the hero. but with what I ve got it does not. and I don't even know where to read about it. I tryed to search in google "object following/tracking" but there is nothing related.

Comment: @fhaddad78 that would be actually introducing a NOP, so that's quite unlikely.

Comment: Web-searching here won't much help - this is a classic debugging challenge. You should write out on paper some inputs to these methods and their expected outputs, and then run them to see where their output differs. That said, +1 for @jskiles1 - I can't see any (x,y) co-ordinates here.

Comment: -1 Low-effort question with misleading title that will not benefit anybody else in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make an object move from a source point to a destination point, you need a few things:

1. Current Position X and Y coordinates
2. Destination Position X and Y coordinates
3. Angle of attack to move to destination from source
4. Velocity with which to move from destination to source

**Pseudocode:**

```
dy = PositionDestination.Y - PositionCurrent.Y
dx = PositionDestination.X - PositionCurrent.X
angle = atan2(dy/dx)

vx = v * cos(angle)
vy = v * sin(angle)

PositionCurrent += Vector(vx, vy)
```

**C#:**

```
 // angle is the arctan placed in the correct quadrant of the Y difference and X difference
 float angleOfAttack = 
      (float)Math.Atan2((double)(PositionDestination.Y - PositionCurrent.Y), 
      (double)(PositionDestination.X - PositionCurrent.X));

 // velocity is the cos(angle*speed), sin(angle*speed)
 Vector2 velocity = 
      new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angleOfAttack) * projectileMoveSpeed,
      (float)Math.Sin(angleOfAttack) * projectileMoveSpeed);

 // new position is +velocity
 PositionCurrent += velocity;
```

So, you get the angle first based on the source and destination coordinates. Then, you get the velocity direction and distance based on angle and speed. Finally, you move the current position to a new location based on the velocity vector.

Comment: I am getting some ideas from your code. What is projectileMoveSpeed? Is AngleOfAttack is angle between two objects right?

Comment: I am just confused, coz my heading is in degrees, but as I see, my heading should follow a coordinates(x,y) i.e. centre point of object.

Comment: `angleOfAttack` is the position between a source and a destination, yes. `projectileMoveSpeed` is the vector length.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I ll try that algorithm you gave me.

Comment: @JustinSkiles hello, i dont know why this one doesnt work https://hastebin.com/vimobodega.cpp, heres the sample ss http://imgur.com/3Rh0xTg